# clusterR returns "argument is of length zero"

Tags: r, cluster-computing, multicore, raster, snow

I've been using the R `raster` package for a long time, but now I really can't get my head around this clusterR problem. I have to compute the SPI index for a netCDF raster. This is done for each cell, taking the cell timeseries and returning the SPI index timeseries for that cell.

The example input file (about 4MB) can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxlZ3Tjj36sNZDZldF80b2EwQ3c/view?usp=sharing).

See the below code:

```
library(raster)
library(SPEI)

calcspi <- function(pr) { #this function calculates the SPI index for each timeseries of values
    pr <- as.numeric(pr)
    if (all(is.na(pr[1:20]))) { #Check that this is not an NA cell
        outspi <- rep(NA, length(pr))
    } else {
        outspi <- fitted(spi(pr, 12, na.rm=TRUE))
    }
    return(outspi)
}

b <- brick("input_crop.nc", varname="pr")
readAll(b) #As requested in the comments

###THIS WORKS BUT IS SLOW:
bc <- calc(b, calcspi)

###THIS DOES NOT:
beginCluster(n=4)

bc <- clusterR(b, calc, args=list(fun="calcspi"))
#[1] "argument is of length zero"
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "snow-try-error" "try-error"
#Error in clusterR(b, calc, args = list(fun = "calcspi")) : cluster error

endCluster()

###THIS DOESN'T EITHER:
beginCluster(n=4)

f <- function(x) calc(x, calcspi)
bc <- clusterR(b, f)
#[1] "argument is of length zero"
#attr(,"class")
#[1] "snow-try-error" "try-error"
#Error in clusterR(b, f) : cluster error

endCluster()
```

`traceback()` is completely useless in this case.
What is wrong?

Comment: This may be related to raster not being able to detect, in the cluster environment, which ncdf package you are using. Can you try `b <- b * 1` (or something equivalent to copy the values out of the ncdf file first)?

Comment: If you provide a trimmed version of the netCDF source file, we could play around with the problem, perhaps look at options beyond your attempts above e.g. data.table..

Comment: Rather, provide an example that does not require a file (unless that is the cause of the problem)

Comment: @RobertH @Shekeine I uploaded an example file (4MB) and added a `readAll()` call, so that the file gets read into memory first. I still can't figure it out. I've used `calc()` with `clusterR()` before without problems... notice that the `fitted(spi())` call is not the culprit, it happens even if I just issue `outspi <- pr * 2` in the `calcspi` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
b <- mybrick
#readAll(b) #As requested in the comments
#parallel processing 
ff <- function(x) calc(x, calcspi)
beginCluster(8)
bc <- clusterR(b, fun = ff,export='calcspi')
endCluster()
```

Comment: Actually it seems that the normal `calc()` version is quite fast now (it takes just 3 seconds), at least for the example dataset. Probably because of some improvement in the code. Still, your fix indeed is valid, good catch!